# loss value is high in the deep learning and accuracy is changing around 50%

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am training a deep learning network using pre-trained VGG-16 . I have high loss around 7-8 and accuracy is around 50%. I want to improve the accuracy.
1. Could you explain me if my data set is set correctly?

```
trdata = ImageDataGenerator()
traindata = 
trdata.flow_from_directory(directory="/Users/khand/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/Case_db/data",target_size=(224,224))
tsdata = ImageDataGenerator()
testdata = tsdata.flow_from_directory(directory="/Users/khand/OneDrive/Desktop/Thesis/Case_db/data", target_size=(224,224))
```

Here is how I set my data set and in the folder of "data" I have 2 subfolder 1 is containing main data other one containing labels.

I think connection between networks and layers are fine since I can train the network.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
early = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=20, verbose=1, mode='auto')
hist = model.fit_generator( steps_per_epoch=10,generator=traindata, validation_data= 
testdata,validation_steps=10,epochs=10,callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint('VGG16-transferlearning.model', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True)])
```

Above how my validation and training goes on and result is below:

> Epoch 1/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 253s 25s/step - loss: 8.1311 - accuracy: 0.4437 - val_loss: 7.5554 - val_accuracy: 0.4875
>   Epoch 2/10
>   C:\Users\khand\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlow-GPU\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py:707: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping.
>     'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
>   10/10 [==============================] - 255s 26s/step - loss: 7.8576 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 5.0369 - val_accuracy: 0.5281
>   Epoch 3/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 263s 26s/step - loss: 8.0590 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 8.0590 - val_accuracy: 0.5094
>   Epoch 4/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 258s 26s/step - loss: 7.6561 - accuracy: 0.5250 - val_loss: 7.0517 - val_accuracy: 0.4765
>   Epoch 5/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 246s 25s/step - loss: 7.9090 - accuracy: 0.4899 - val_loss: 9.0664 - val_accuracy: 0.5281
>   Epoch 6/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 257s 26s/step - loss: 7.7065 - accuracy: 0.5219 - val_loss: 8.5627 - val_accuracy: 0.4812
>   Epoch 7/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 244s 24s/step - loss: 7.9079 - accuracy: 0.5094 - val_loss: 8.5627 - val_accuracy: 0.5031
>   Epoch 8/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 231s 23s/step - loss: 8.5147 - accuracy: 0.4765 - val_loss: 5.5406 - val_accuracy: 0.4966
>   Epoch 9/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 251s 25s/step - loss: 8.3613 - accuracy: 0.4812 - val_loss: 5.5406 - val_accuracy: 0.4938
>   Epoch 10/10
>   10/10 [==============================] - 247s 25s/step - loss: 8.0087 - accuracy: 0.5031 - val_loss: 8.5627 - val_accuracy: 0.4906

If you have any suggestion please feel free to help

Comment: My guess is that the learning rate is too big, please include model and optimizer configuration

Comment: from keras.optimizers import Adam
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
what is normal learning rate  ?